# reading data from 16*2 LCD (HD44780) using at89c52

Tags: c, embedded, lcd

I am interfacing 16*2 with AT89C52 for my project and scroll the characters. I am able to rotate the content with LCD but I have to tweak the code a little bit to show character that is at 90H to 80H location. For this i have to read the character but i cant seem to find any examples on the internet. i know i have to set RW pin but need help after that

```
char str1[] = "Abcdefghi";
lcd_init();
lcd_cmd(loc);
prt_string(str1);
while(1)
{
    lcd_cmd(0x1c);
}
```

where prt_string is used to print string.Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: This question lacks clarity.  The code you have posted could do anything, it is not clear what relevance it has, it is just function calls to code that could go anything

Comment: https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/lcd-interfacing-with-8051-microcontroller-89s52

Comment: There's nothing to it!  Just set the address and read the data port.

Comment: @EsmaeelE every function in that program is to write data, i want a function to read data

Comment: @tonypdmtr , sorry im dump but the part of reading data, idk how to do it

Comment: @Clifford, i'm sorry if i wasn't clear, the code i showed is scrolling text in LCD but i want it to work such that as soon as text disappears from display it should show at home position

Comment: @JerseyDevil That is a clearer explanation, but it is information you need in the question not in a comment.  Update the question ; that is how SO works, it is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Even then, it is not clear whether you want an answer in terms of the existing API, or code directly accessing the hardware.  If the first then you need to document or reference the available API, if the latter then you need to provide either details of the target processor and it's connection to the display, or the code if the existing API, or both.

Comment: This may be an XY problem; one where you ask about your solution rather than the actual problem.  Your comment suggests that.  Ask about how to achieve the desired display result rather than the lower level question of how to read the display memory - maybe you don't have to.